# How to install AviSynth+ 32-bit?

Tags: avisynth

I have used and installed AviSynth+ 64-bit on a machine. I then wanted to install AviSynth+ 32-bit [to use the watermark filter](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/396116-Adding-a-watermark-to-videos#post2574751). I followed [these instructions](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=172124) to install 32-bit, changed the registry keys, and got a blue screen of death.

After a fresh reinstallation of the Windows system, I want to install 32-bit AviSynth+ only and avoid another blue screen of death.

On [the new version 3.5.1 of AviSynth+](https://github.com/AviSynth/AviSynthPlus/releases/tag/v3.5.1), is XP the 32-bit version, or is any installer able to install a 32-bit version?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with having installed both 32- and 64-bit version of AviSynth on your 64-bit machine, if you correctly placed 32-bit plugins vs. 64-bit ones to their appropriate places.

AviSynth is a frame server, it means, you never call it directly - *other* program call it back. It means that for example

- 64-bit Media Player Classic will call the 64-bit version of AviSynth,
- 32-bit Media Player Classic will call the 32-bit version of AviSynth.

Similarly

- 64-bit FFmpeg will call the 64-bit version of AviSynth,
- 32-bit FFmpeg will call the 32-bit version of AviSynth.

I guess that your problem lies in your FFmpeg installation — you have probably 64-bit, and it means that in the process of converting your .avs script to some media file the FFmpeg calls 64-bit version of AviSynth, and you need the 32-bit (because of your 32-bit filter).

So my advice is, install both 32- and 64-bit versions of FFmpeg (into different directories) and use the appropriate one for every particular case.

Comment: I do not see a folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\AviSynth`or `C:\Program Files\AviSynth`. Where is AviSynth installed, so I can copy plugins there? And I do not see a 32-bit version of Media Player Classic at the [K-Lite codec pack mega](https://www.codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_mega.htm), where can I get the 32-bit version of Media Player Classic?

Comment: "Where is AviSynth installed?" See the Registry, key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Avisynth` for 64-bit,  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Avisynth` for 32-bit.

Comment: K-Lite codec pack installs both 32- and 64-bit version of Media Player Classic, `c:\Program Files (x86)\K-Lite Codec Pack\MPC-HC\mpc-hc.exe` is 32-bit, `c:\Program Files (x86)\K-Lite Codec Pack\MPC-HC64\mpc-hc64.exe` is 64-bit.

Comment: I found the location of installation by launching the `Registry Editor` app and going to those paths: AviSynth+ 64-bit is at `C:\Program Files (x86)\AviSynth+\`, AviSynth+ 32-bit shows the path where I extracted the universal installer, say `C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\UniversalAvisynthInstaller\AVSPLUS_x86`. K-Lite only installed the 64-bit version and `C:\Program Files (x86)\K_Lite Codec Pack` has no `MPC-HC` directory.

Comment: Please try find `mpc-hc.exe` and `mpc-hc-64.exe` by other way — IMHO the best way is to install and use [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) — it's for free and very useful.

Comment: "Everything" does find `mpc-hc64.exe` at that location (`C:\Program Files (x86)\K_Lite Codec Pack\MPC-HC64`. A search for `mpc-hc.exe` returns "0 objects".